# bool query does not support [search_after] -- Elastic Search error

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

I am trying to query my index and filtering according to geo-distance at the same time though paginate through my index but I ma getting this error

**Error:**

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "parsing_exception",
                "reason": "bool query does not support [search_after]",
                "line": 7,
                "col": 21
            }
        ],
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "bool query does not support [search_after]",
        "line": 7,
        "col": 21
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

**Actual Query:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "search_after": [1463538857, "654323"],
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "150km",
                    "location" : {
                        "lat" : xxxx,
                        "lon" : xxxxx
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put `search_after` out of `query`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : {
                "match_all" : {}
            },
            "filter" : {
                "geo_distance" : {
                    "distance" : "150km",
                    "location" : {
                        "lat" : xxxx,
                        "lon" : xxxxx
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    search_after": [1463538857, "654323"]
 }
```

So as name implies `search_after` will start matching after given value. You need to specify some ordering for that. For example in the example from [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-search-after.html)

```
GET twitter/_search
{
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title" : "elasticsearch"
        }
    },
    "search_after": [1463538857, "654323"],
    "sort": [
        {"date": "asc"},
        {"tie_breaker_id": "asc"}
    ]
}
```

first sorts documents based on `date` and `tie_breaker_id` fields so `"search_after": [1463538857, "654323"]` statement means begin searching after date `1463538857` and tie_breaker_id `"654323"`

So what you need to do here is to sort documents based on some field and after provide search_after with desired value.

Comment: Thank you I did what you say. The old error has gone now I am facing another could you help? 
"reason": "Sort must contain at least one field.""

Comment: Can you help with this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60991499/elasticsearch-autocomplete-suggester?noredirect=1#comment107913286_60991499