# Elasticsearch autocomplete suggester

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I want to implement autocomplete feature in ES I have followed [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters.html#completion-suggester) tutorial from ES documentations

my Indexing is:

```
{
    "properties" : {
            "suggest" : {
                "type" : "completion"
            },
            "titleKeyword" : {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am putting text value in `titleKeyword`  field

then I queried  like follows

```
{
  "suggest" : {
    "my-suggestion" : {
      "text" : "iphone",
      "term" : {
        "field" : "titleKeyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is:

```
...
    "suggest": {
        "my-suggestion": [
            {
                "text": "iphone",
                "offset": 0,
                "length": 6,
                "options": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

expected result is

```
options:[iphone x, iphone 11, iphone 11 pro, iphone 7]
```

**Note**: titles are complete sentences like "iPhone x 64gb black"

as far as I understood from the documentation that I have to give the suggestions in "advance" when creating the document which is impossible in my case is there any way to implement this feature without putting suggestions manually?

Thanks

Comment: so basically you have documents conatining iphone x, iphone 11, iphone 11 pro, iphone 7 and when searched for `iphone` you want all of them to appear in search result ?

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja exactly like that

Comment: Provided answer according to your requirement :)

Comment: did you get a chance to go through my answer

Comment: @OpsterElasticsearchNinja
Thank you very much for your answer but unfortunately, it doesn't address my case exactly I could do regex query and fetch the documents that contain the queried text  (since the title may contains more tahn one word like iphone x 32gb storage silver )
so when i write iphone i want to suggest to me iphone x, iphone 7 and so on 
i.e not the document title but a keyword from the document title

Answer (score 1):

For this simple requirement, no need to use the Elasticsearch suggestor which is difficult to understand and some part of it is still under development, More info on what all to take care when building advance autocomplete is in my [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60584211/4039431).

**Coming to your requirements which can be easily solved using the `text` field(looks like you are using `keyword` type) and simple match query as shown below:**

### Index Def

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "model_name": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Index all 4 types of `iphone`

```
{
   "model_name" : "iphone x"
}

{
   "model_name" : "iphone 11"
}

{
   "model_name" : "iphone 11 pro"
}

{
   "model_name" : "iphone 7"
}
```

### Search query (`iphone` will bring all four docs)

```
{
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "model_name": {
                "query": "iphone"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Search result

```
{
            "_index": "so_auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.110377684,
            "_source": {
               "model_name": "iphone x"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so_auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.110377684,
            "_source": {
               "model_name": "iphone 11"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so_auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "4",
            "_score": 0.110377684,
            "_source": {
               "model_name": "iphone 7"
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "so_auto",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 0.09271726,
            "_source": {
               "model_name": "iphone 11 pro"
            }
         }
      ]
```